# mysql_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, mysql, string, parameters

here is my code and somebody tell my how to use mySQL instead of mySQLi

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = 'cms';

    $conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($conn,$db_name);

?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Read the manual: [mysql_select_db](http://www.php.net/mysql_select_db)

Comment: First parameter should be database name

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is clearly stated in the PHP documentation

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place $db_name as first parameter.

```
mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);
```

instead of

```
mysql_select_db($conn,$db_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($db_name, $conn);
```

Stop using `mysql`, its deprecated. Use `mysqli`. Read the [manual](https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db)
for more details.

Answer (score 0):

your are using parameter in wrong format.
dbname comes first and then connection link

```
mysql_select_db ( string $database_name [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

 mysql_select_db($db_name, $conn);
```

docs link:

https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db

Note: try to use mysqli_*

Answer (score 0):

In [mysql_select_db()](https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db), DB name should be the first params which is of String type. Also $conn is not a string type variable, it is a resource type variable.

Since you are trying to assign `resource` variable to String type variable you got error.

Hence change  this

`mysql_select_db($conn,$db_name);`

to

```
mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = 'cms';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
?>
```

[More here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) Db name will be last.